# Using scroll wheel to zoom in/out

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I know this is available in version 2.x of Google Maps API. But I couldn't find how to use it in v3, I'm not even sure if it's implemented yet. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Apparently, it's available now in v3 too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.

This functionality isn't supported by the v3 API yet.  See the [Feature Request: Add Scroll wheel zoom in v3](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=1351).

Update:

Looks like someone has developed a [third party library](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/scrollwheelzoom/1.0/) to do this stuff (via [ChrisB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/53487/chris-b)).

Comment: Thanks. I just couldn't see any reason why it shouldn't be in v3 when it was already available in v2.x

Comment: Understandable.  I guess you have to keep in mind the v3 is not an iterative upgrade from v2, but a complete re-write.  Google have released it early for our benefit, but it is not all there yet :).